# Angular $watch just parent object instead of its multiple children

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have a div, listing properties of the object POI = `{"address":"Martinsicuro (TE), Italy", "phone":"+39 333 45657", "website':'http://mysite.it"}`. The object POI si owned by a Service. The directive's controller has the function `getPoi()` that gets the POI from the service, and returns it to the directive.

My current HTML is something like this:

```
<table ng-controller="Controller as ctrl">
    <tr> <!-- address -->
        <td>{{ctrl.getPoi().address}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- phone -->                   
        <td>{{ctrl.getPoi().phone}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!-- website -->
        <td>
            <a ng-href="{{ctrl.getPoi().website}}"> 
                {{ctrl.getPoi().website}}
            </a>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

The controller

```
.controller('Controller', function(CurrentPoiService)
{

  this.getPoi = function()
    { return CurrentPoiService.POI; }
}
```

The service

```
.service('CurrentPoiService', function()
{

  this.POI = {"address":"Martinsicuro (TE), Italy", "phone":"+39 333 45657", "website':'http://mysite.it"}
}
```

In this way I am adding 3 watchers. Is there a way to add just 1 watcher, since it's the same parent object? Here it is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c6apvpq/)
Thank you

[UPDATE 1]
This is the (still not working) [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47qfL657/2/) using the solution proposed by @Charlie

[UPDATE 2]
This is the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47qfL657/7/)

Comment: this doesn't make sense.  your view should *never* be making calls to a data service like this.  these expressions aren't two way bound to an object, they are bound to the result of a function, which means each one could be referring to a completely different result.

Comment: ctrl.getPoi() returns Service.poi, so it's not a new object each time, it's the reference always to the same object. I'd use it just to show the properties, so I don't need the 2 way binding.

Comment: This is still violating one of the major principles of MVC design, and leading you to ask how to solve a false problem, since the number of watchers is based on the number of expressions in use;  Angular isn't watching the **property**, it is watching the **expression**.  you could use the bind once expression syntax (`::`), but you wouldn't notice the difference in this contrived example, because the code you are using to check for watchers doesn't change the count if the watchers are removed after they have been counted.

Comment: bottom line is, just because people have posted articles about how evil `$$watchers` are doesn't mean that every app needs to be optimized down to 0.  It's probably much more important to your app that you follow proper Separation Of Concerns, which have functional implications for your application, rather than some hyper optimized theory.

Comment: @Charlie 's solution doesn't work, since POI is a complex object. What would be a good way to solve my problem? I have the object POI owned by a service because it must be shared among the several pages (like the user logged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Claies has mentioned in a comment, you should never call your data from 
the view through a function this way.

In this scenario you can create a watch for the `POI` object with the `objectEquality` argument `true` to watch the properties of the object in a single $watch. Then find your elements inside the listener and change the value in the way you want.

```
$scope.$watch('POI', function(){

    //Assume that $scope.propertyIndex is the current property to display

    angular.element($document[0].querySelector("#myTd" + $scope.propertyIndex)).html(POI.address);
    angular.element($document[0].querySelector("#myTd" + $scope.propertyIndex)).html(POI.phone);
    //etc...

}, true);
```

You have a better control this way. But please keep in mind that this method is not suitable if POI is a complex object.

UPDATE:

Here is a working example of showing a random number every second using a watch and a factory. You should be able to learn from this and apply it to your project.

```
            myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, dataSource) {

                 $scope.poi = {rand: 0};    

                 $scope.$watch('poi', function() {
                    $('#rand').html($scope.poi.rand);
                 }, true);

                dataSource.open($scope);               

            });

            myApp.factory('dataSource', function($interval) {                

                return {                       
                            open: function(scope){
                                $interval(function() {
                                    scope.poi.rand = Math.random();
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                }    
            });
```

Comment: what's the difference between `angular.element($document[0].querySelector("#myTd"))` and `$('#myTd')` ? Thank you

Comment: anyway... POI is something like `{'address' : '...', 'phone' : '...'}` so it's a complex object.. and your solution doesn't work. Even `$watching` just the id of the object  `$scope.$watch(CurrentPoiService.POI.id, function(){..})` it doesn't work.

Comment: How many properties and nested properties do you have in POI? Answer to your first comment is that one is JQuery way and the other is Angular way.

Comment: something like 15 properties, 4 of them have nested properties.  I am using  my mechanism also for other objects showed in the page. Maybe the best solution would be mixing my way and yours, according to @Claies to keep the Separation Of Concerns. But I can't make your solution to work.

Comment: Are you setting the objectEquality argument to true in your code?

Comment: Also please note that not being able to see your full code, I have assumed in my solution that POI is changed by an external mechanism (like service) and you need to record all these changes in your markup. Hope this helps you getting it to work.

Comment: Here it is a [JSFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/47qfL657/2/) with your solution. I put it also in my question

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. Your fiddle has some problems in it. Please see from the answer and apply it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try inside your controller :

```
$scope.POI = ctrl.getPoi();
```

HTML :

```
<tr> <!-- address -->
    <td>{{POI.address}}</td>
</tr>
<tr> <!-- phone -->                   
    <td>{{POI.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: actually `ctrl.getPoi()`,  retrieves the object POI from a service, so I can't initialize `$scope.POI = ctrl.getPoi()`, otherwise when the service.POI change, `$scope.POI`  is not updated.

Comment: Could you update your post, included your service (simplified) ?

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle. Thank you